# How to reduce the length of output encryption in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-4

I'm using a custom My_encrypt.php library file.

```
 $this->encrypt->encode(1);
```

Output :

```
roI2urYfzQClEpLvatI8A8ZTrRkwEduAmMWllVBBLoaucnB0t2UCXcFVCiprA9aMOhP7T4wZb0ZOhKRTvWvslQXX
```

How can I reduce the length of this output? I know it's secure, but I need a shorter length.

Comment: You can try the different ciphers and modes listed in the encoding documentation with `$this->encryption->initialize` method. (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html#configuring-the-library)[https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html#configuring-the-library]

Comment: ohk thank you. i will try it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to reduce the length of this output.

**Why** do you want to do this? The encryption CodeIgniter provides is using *authenticated encryption*. Confidentiality without integrity is the same as no confidentiality.

Are you trying to encrypt database IDs for URLs? [See this instead](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).